# How to generate ByteCode and Abi from a go smart contract (chaincode)?

Tags: go, bytecode, solidity, smartcontracts, abi

I have an environment that can deploy smart contract using ByteCode and ABI. But my smart contract is written in Go not in Solidity.

Is it possible to generate ByteCode and ABI from a smart contract written in go (chaincode)? Or is it possible to convert Go smart contract to Solidity smart contract?

Thanks in advance.

I expect some librairies that could help me generate ABI and bytecode from a chaincode. Or any suggestions to do that.